# How can I derive an action name based on the mesh selected?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, transforms, keyframes

I have a simple cube that has a keyframed location from Frame 1 to Frame 48

[image]

Here is a code that shifts the keyframes by 2

```
import bpy

# Configuration
action_name = 'CubeAction'
data_path = 'location'
index = 2                   # Z axis

# Find the appropriate action
action = bpy.data.actions.get(action_name)
if action:
    # From this action, retrieve the appropriate F-Curve
    fcurve = action.fcurves.find(data_path = data_path, index = index)
    if fcurve:
        # Iterate over all keyframes
        for kfp in fcurve.keyframe_points:
            # Print current keyframe info
            print('Frame = {:04}; Value = {}'.format(kfp.co[0], kfp.co[1]))
            # Change keyframe data
            # Push back in time by 2 frames
            kfp.co[0] += 2
```

However, instead of "action_name = 'CubeAction'", I want to select a mesh and automatically get the action name associated with the mesh, is this possible?

So, for example, if I selected Cube.002 then it should automatically get 'CubeAction.002' as action name. Is this possible?

Comment: should be roughly `action = bpy.context.active_object.animation_data.action.name`

Comment: Works Perfectly. Thank you.